# XML protection?

Tags: php, html, xml, forms

I have a few publicly accessible XML files stored on a webserver that I can update via non-publicly accessible html and php files. I have secured the php files by using sessions and tokens. I was just wondering if there was anything I'm missing.

Question: Could any one inject data into XML files by creating their own html form and php files? What additional measures could be taken to fully secure XML files?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. You say the XML files are on a webserver.

Q: Who (what users on the webserver) can write to the files? Are they user-writable, group writable or world-writable?

Ideal scenario: only the owning user can write to the files. This prevents other people on the server (except root) from messing with them.

#### 2.You say you can update the XML filesusing PHP scripts, and that you secured the PHP scripts (these will probably be your weakest link)

Q: How are they secured? Do you require a logon on the webserver? Are you using SSL? Or did you just throw together a form with some username and password? Are they writable, and to whom?

Answer to your question: if the XML files are writable only to a specific user (say 'paradox') and the PHP script(s) updating the files are run as that user but not writable by other users, your files are as safe as the weakest link in your computer, server, network and scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I think it only depends on the way you've developed the private administrative area.

For example you must ensure that the php script that directly writes the xml files are someway protected by unhautorized accesses (session, password, .htaccess, auth token, etc...) obviously you shouldn't protect only the administrative forms (user interface)...

If you can provide more details on the implementation it would be easier to help...

Answer (score 0):

"I have a few publicly accessible XML files stored on a webserver that I can update via non-publicly accessible html and php files. I have secured the php files by using sessions and tokens. I was just wondering if there was anything I'm missing." - Well if you have a session started you might display links to the XML file(s) here. If no session no links, make sense? Example: If your web root is /var/www/html you might make a separate directory for the XML file(s) like /var/www/xml now this folder is not assessable from the URL but you can link the file(s) to be called from your PHP script on successful session authentication.

```
// index.php (pseudo code)
if($authenticated) {
   // echo '<a href="/var/www/xml/file.xml">Display XML</a>';
} else {
   // no links to files
}
```

"Question: Could any one inject data into XML files by creating their own html form and php files? What additional measures could be taken to fully secure XML files?" - The answer is yes, people can create a php (or other language) to take your xml and modify it's content. But they can not modify the XML on your site (The XML that your scripts use), they can read the XML from your site and parse it out or manipulate it on another site (Think something like web services). I'm not sure how you have your XML permissions and I'm not aware of any XML exploits (But I'm sure there are some), but injecting XML into your XML should be very difficult. You might consider read-only file permission for the XML file(s) to limit the functionality of the end user as well.

Hope this helps